# How to display details of listview selected item on another activity?

Tags: android, mysql, listview, android-volley

Here is my code... which i displayed listview data... Now i want to fetch other details under this id

I want to fetch from database based on the Growers ID. Which is get from the listview

```
 public class FarmerDetails extends Activity implements OnClickListener
    {
    private TextView tv;
    private Button btnView;
    private TextView textViewResult;

     @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.farmerdetails);

            btnView = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bView);
            textViewResult = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewResult);

            btnView.setOnClickListener(this);
            tv=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv1);


     }
     private void getData(final String value) {
         Intent i = getIntent();
            String code = i.getStringExtra("itemValue");
            tv.setText("Grower's ID: "+code);

            String url = Config.DATA_Details+tv.getText().toString().trim();

            StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    showJSON(response);
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(FarmerDetails.this,error.getMessage().toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
            }

            RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
            requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
        }

        private void showJSON(String response){
            String ccri="";
            String name="";
            String address="";
            String taluk="";
            String punch = "";
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                JSONArray result = jsonObject.getJSONArray(Config.JSON_ARRAY);
                JSONObject farmerData = result.getJSONObject(0);
                ccri=farmerData.getString(Config.KEY_CCRI);
                name = farmerData.getString(Config.KEY_NAME);
                address = farmerData.getString(Config.KEY_ADDRESS);
                taluk = farmerData.getString(Config.KEY_TALUK);
                punch=farmerData.getString(Config.KEY_PUNCH);
            } 
            catch (JSONException e) 
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            textViewResult.setText("CCRI Code:\t"+ccri+"Name:\t"+name+"\nAddress:\t" +address+ "\nTaluk:\t"+taluk+"\nPunchayat:\t"+punch);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            getData();
        }    
    }
```

In my code only ID is displaying... fetching is not performing.. Plz help!!

Comment: try this on textview id .getText().toString();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is kinda complicated.

1. you'll have to check out if ur url is right. Print the url in
   console and type it in some browser do the GET request. If there's
   no response, well it might be your problem. Maybe you did not
   compose the url right.
2. if there's some response in step 1, ask the server guy what's going
   on there. and wait.